# is my code vulnerable to SQL injection

Tags: php, sql

I just want to know if my code is vulnerable in SQL injection
i have this code for login and i know if it is safe to use and if it can prevent from any SQL injection.

here is my code.

```
  <?php
  class LTID
  {
  private $db;

  function __construct($DB_con)
  {
    $this->db = $DB_con;
  }
  public function login($username,$password)
  {
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                if(password_verify($password, $userRow['password']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id']
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }       
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: No it's not vulnerable since you're using prepared statements.

Comment: is safe for me to use this kind of code?

Comment: Prepared statement is ok. I have one question instead taking out password from database cant you check the password in database itself. I think that will be more secure because your password will be safe always with in the database.

Comment: @Sk_ what do yoou mean by that?

Comment: @Sk - The answer is "no" with password_hash()/password_verify(), because it's a PHP function and not a database function; and nor would you want to change it: it is considered the strongest method of handling password hashes these days, and not to be lightly replaced with any alternative

Comment: Your password is in $userRow['password'] and then you are verifying the password. Means the password outside the database now. Instead taking out the password why cant you check this with in database itself. Check the username and password with the query. If the username and password match do what ever you want. In this case password wont be visible. You are checking inside database.

Comment: I'm a little bit confuse by now.some told me that it safe.

Comment: @sk can you please edit my code for my better ynderstanding.

Comment: @Sk_ What do you mean the password is "out of the database" ? It's a PHP script, it's running on the server noone can see the password

Comment: @Sk_ No, the password is ___not___ out of the database; the password __hash__ has been fetched (temporarily) from the database to the PHP script for validation against the password that the user has entered.... stop trying to confuse people while they're learning

Comment: @kier - Sk_ is being disingenuous (and not strictly accurate either) - using password_hash()/password_verify() together with your prepared atatement with bind variables is as safe as PHP/database can be.... though I hope you're using https (with TLS) for your webserver request, and not straight http

Comment: @MarkBaker how to use that https?

Comment: @kier - you need to configure your webserver to use https, and get a security certificate

Comment: @MarkBaker i dont have any idea about that https,,can you help me please?

Comment: [how to configure https on apache 2](https://beeznest.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/how-to-configure-https-on-apache-2/)

Comment: @markbaker thanks man..

Answer (score 2):

Prepared queries are immune to SQL injection because the values are not mixed with the SQL code.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `PDO` and you are using Prepared Statements, so no your code is not vulnerable to SQL Injection.

From what I see the password is also hashed in the database and since you use `password_verify` to validate the password I assume the password is hashed with `password_hash`.

Overall your code looks pretty safe

Comment: Yeah.my password is hashed

Comment: I imagined. There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. Good job!!

Comment: @dimlucas.i'm a little confuse because the comment above by sk is a little bit confusing for me.

Comment: What he is saying is indeed confusing, but there is nothing wrong with fetching the password from the database and checking it against the user's input. A PHP script cannot be intercepted, noone can see what is essentially running on the server so, again, no worries you're code is perfect.

Comment: Yeah.thats why im little bit confuse by the comment